# The normal at $P(ap^2,2ap)$ on a parabola also meets $Q$. Show that the locus of the intersection of tangents at $P$ and $Q$ is $y^2(x+2a)+4a^3=0$

Tags: conic-sections

> If the normal at $P(ap^2,2ap)$ to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ meets the curve again at $Q(aq^2,2aq)$, show that $p^2+pq+2=0$. Show that the equation of the locus of the point of intersection of the tangents at $P$ and $Q$ to the parabola is $y^2(x+2a)+4a^3=0$.

Comment: Is the point P and Q identical?

Comment: no, typing wrongly.I'm edited the question .

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects that questions include something of what the asker knows of the problem at hand. (What have you tried? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you aren't familiar. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3332191/edit) to make clarifications.

Comment: The first part of your question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236502/the-normal-at-tat2-2at-of-parabola-y2-4ax-meets-the-parabola-again-at-s?rq=1, which you can find in the handy list of related questions at right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the parabola is $x=\frac{y^2}{4a}$. I know that the angular coefficent of the tangent line to the parabolais $m=2ay_0+b=2\cdot \frac{1}{4a}y_0=\frac{y_0}{2a}$ where $y_0$ is the $y$ coordinate of the tangency point and $a,b$ are coefficents of $x=ay^2+by+c$. The tangent line so is: $x-ap^2=\frac{1}{2a}(y-2ap)$ so $x+ap^2=py$. The normal line has angular coefficent $m_1=-\frac{2a}{y_0}$. The normal has equation: $x-x_0=-\frac{2a}{y_0}(y-y_0)$. Substituing the values of $x_0$ and $y_0$, I obtain: $x-ap^2=-\frac{1}{q}(y-2ap)$. Now, the solutions of the system: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x-ap^2=-\frac{1}{q}(y-2ap)
\\ x=\frac{y^2}{4a}
\end{matrix}\right.$$ are: $x=aq^2$ and $y=2aq$. Substituing another time, I have: $$a(q-p)(q+p)=-\frac{1}{q}\cdot 2a(q-p)$$ and so: $$q^2+pq+2=0$$